# Book where someone from the civil war died and became a zombie because his family didn't put wax in his ears

Tags: story-identification, books

In book 3 the plot is that this civil war dude died and since his family forgot to put wax in his ears he became a zombie. His master wants gold under the main character's new school and the main character can see and talk to ghosts. Also the boy's father went to this school. The kid has a dog who helps find the gold and this kid has a friend who helped him. The other thing I remember is some dude burned to death from a fire and locked door in the school and baron Samedi is mentioned.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[The Smoky Corridor](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7327316-the-smoky-corridor) by Chris Grabenstein. It is book 3 of his [Haunted Mystery](https://www.goodreads.com/series/60541-haunted-mystery) series.

[image: The Smoky Corridor]

The main character is *Zack*, and as you say he can talk to ghosts:

> Zack is about to start at his new school, and his dad, who went there years before, tells Zack the stories of the haunted janitor’s closet, the spectre of a dead crossing guard, and the Donnelly brothers, who perished in a suspicious fire. Dad doesn’t know that Zack has already met the Donnellys’ ghosts, who have warned Zack that there is an evil zombie under the school. Zack also learns that while zombies are usually content eating corpses, if they happen to bite someone who isn’t dead, that person also becomes a zombie.

Though the ears are sealed with clay not wax:

> Since McNulty, a farm boy from Indiana, had no family in Louisiana to seal up his ears with clay to make him deaf to the sorcerer’s call, his wispy soul flew up through the mucky soil to be trapped as easily as a firefly in a jar. Then the lifeless body, lacking a soul and, therefore, drained of all free will, had no choice but to crawl out of his casket and dig his way back into life.
>
> On that fateful April night, Cyrus McNulty and sixty-five other men rose from the dead to become Pettimore’s army of slaves

Comment: Thank you this was stuck in my head I read it when I was younger and it popped into my head and I could not remember the name again thank you so much!!!!!!!!!!!